# CRM 2011 Get selected items from lookup

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, subgrid

I have issue with CRM 2011. 
We have SubGrid with some entity and I need get selected items from this subgrid and send to another form.(For example onSave event)
How it is possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
var records = Xrm.Page.getControl({grid name})._control.get_innerControl().get_selectedRecords();
```

where {grid name} would be the name of the grid in the properties window.